# How to customize one specific field in Symfony Forms

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am rendering a form that contains several **choice** fields. I want to render **one specific choice field** differently from the other ones.

I've tried to use:

```
{% form_theme form 'MyBundle:Form:my-choice-field.html.twig' %}
{{ form_widget(field) }}
```

But that changes the look and feel of **all choice fields** in that form. If I place *form_theme* right next to the field I want to render differently, it does nothing.

I have thought of creating a new Form Type but it seems overkilling, I just want a different style for that specific field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the doc there is a section describing [how to personalize an individual field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field), for example to customize the `name` field of a `product` entity only:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _product_name_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

Here, the `_product_name_widget` fragment defines the template to use for the field whose id is `product_name` (and name is `product[name]`).

You can also override the markup for an entire field row using the same method:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _product_name_row %}
    <div class="name_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{{ form_row(form.name) }}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but for some reason I don't understand it doesn't work. Also the new block is rendered twice, which is expected twig's behavior but it's a pain: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5475

I'll keep trying, thanks for the answer.